# Is it safe to set recursive properties with PHP object?

Tags: php, oop, object, properties, recursion

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find an answer. What I'm wondering is if it's safe or good practice to use recursive objects in PHP.  To create an object as a property of another object, that contains a property with a reference to the containing object...

```
<?php

    class User
    {
        public $database;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->database = new Database($this);
        }
    }

    Class Database
    {
        private $user;

        public function __construct(User $user) {
            $this->user = $user;
        }

        public function doSomethingForUser() {
            // Call db or get info for this user
        }
    }
```

And then use it as follows...

```
    <?php
        $bar = new User();
        $bar->database->doSomethingForUser();
    ?>
```

I'be just noticed that i've had problems using certain functions such as array_multisort (Specifically "PHP Fatal error:  Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?") when trying to sort an array of objects, and when I use var_dump, it shows some properties as being recursive...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It is safe as long as you are aware of what you are doing, and you know how to work around it. Obviously, if you are using array_multisort, you are not working around the circular reference.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm getting a little confused ... any ideas on how I would handle trying to sort an array of objects which contain circular references?

Comment: Simple.  Assuming you don't need to go all the way down, just sort the top-level array.  You don't need to recursively sort; just use something like `usort` with a comparator function that compares the two objects correctly.

Comment: I think this question is pretty serious and deserves a lot more exposure. This situation happens when an object needs to access properties of it's holder which is a completely different class.

Answer (score 4):

Before PHP 5.3, this could cause a problem.  PHP used to do reference counting, and circular references used to keep the object from getting GCed.

Now that 5.3 implements a decent garbage collector, this isn't quite as much of an issue.  But passing such objects to any function that traverses the object graph could still cause infinite recursion, if the function isn't aware of the possibility and prepared to handle it.  (I think `var_dump` handles recursion decently, but recursively sorting such objects will probably cause all kinds of trouble.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `bar->database->any_method()` won't work because `database` is private.

When you create a recursive reference to an object in PHP, it's actually pretty good about it -- it just uses the existing reference and apparently doesn't create a lot more memory.  In this case, you're not creating a non-deterministic level of recursion -- it's just one set of objects, so an overflow is unlikely unless you're creating tons of these objects (and it would probably be for a different reason).

If you do a `var_dump` on `User`, you'll see:

```
object(User)#1 (1) {
  ["database:private"]=>
  object(Database)#2 (1) {
    ["user:private"]=>
    object(User)#1 (1) {
      ["database:private"]=>
      object(Database)#2 (1) {
        ["user:private"]=>
        *RECURSION*
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...so PHP notices the recursion.

I'd also have to ask *why* you would do that in this instance.

Comment: Yea I realized I made the private type I meant it to be public .... Anyway I was trying to seperate database method from my user methods, so that everytime I create a user object, it has a database object containing all methods that will handle retrieving data for that specific user